# Angular build error with bootstrap 4.0.0

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I am wanting to use some ng-bootstrap components.  It requires bootstrap 4.  When I install 4 and try to build, I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
```

I have can downgrade to bootstrap 3.3.7 and my build problem goes away but the component is not styled correctly.  I am suspecting I need to get 4.0.0 for styling.

I am running angular cli version 1.6.3.
I did not install jquery or popper.js even though npm indicates I have that as an unmet peer dependency.

My package.json is pretty vanilla:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.2",
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"rxjs": "^5.5.2",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"
 },
```

My styles entry in angular-cli.json:

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```

Any ideas on what the build issue is with 4?

Answer (score 0):

I saw a lot of comments about importing bootstrap instead of including it in the styles array.  That felt a little bit of a workaround.  In the end I was able to fix by upgrading the angular cli to the latest (which right now is 1.7.4)